# How should I modify piping for a Burnham Series 2E when the Indirect Water Heater is not used?

Tags: hvac, boiler

Can you provide a sketch (and if possible, a photo of a similar layout) of the piping if I omit the Indirect Water Heater as shown in the attached image taken from page 11 of the Burnham Series 2 installation manual? I will be using the Caleffi NA553362 Boiler Trim Kit w/ AutoFill & Backflow & 1" Threaded Air Separator & 4.4 Gal. Expansion Tank.

[image]

Comment: would you have any use for the associated piping?

Comment: The simple thing would be to (conceptually) replace the IWH with an elbow to connect the two pipes that lead in & out of it. More importantly, do you _need_ that plumbing in the first place? Honestly, this sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) - what are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just delete the T's running to and from the indirectly heated tank, plus everything on the tank heating loop: pipes, circulator pump, the tank itself, and the tank's thermostat.

Effectively the tank is just another heating zone, though it's often given a higher priority because people gripe more about water not being hot enough than about the house temporarily cooling by a much smaller amount.

Comment: Thank you keshlam...I was concerned about spacing and the issue of higher priority...and your comment clarifies this issue...I will be adding other zones after the initial hook up

Comment: For some boilers, a loop is required right at the boiler in addition to the other zones; follow manufacturer's installation instructions.